# PHP parser: braces around variables

Tags: php

I was wondering, how is the semantics of braces exactly defined
inside PHP? For instance, suppose we have defined:

```
$a = "foo";
```

then what are the differences among:

```
echo "${a}";

echo "{$a}";
```

that is, are there any circumstances where the placement of the
dollar sign outside the braces as opposed to within braces makes
a difference or is the result always the same (with braces used
to group just about anything)?

Comment: based on previous questions of yours, it looks like you have a braces {c}{o}{m}{p}{l}{e}{x}

Answer (score 9):

There are a lot of possibilities for braces (such as omitting them), and things get even more complicated when dealing with objects or arrays.

I prefer interpolation to concatenation, and I prefer to omit braces when not necessary.  Sometimes, they are.

You cannot use object operators with `${}` syntax.  You must use `{$...}` when calling methods, or chaining operators (if you have only one operator such as to get a member, the braces may be omitted).

The `${}` syntax can be used for variable variables:

```
$y = 'x';
$x = 'hello';
echo "${$y}"; //hello
```

The `$$` syntax does not interpolate in a string, making `${}` necessary for interpolation.  You can also use strings (`${'y'}`) and even concatenate within a `${}` block.  However, variable variables can probably be considered a bad thing.

For arrays, either will work `${foo['bar']}` vs. `{$foo['bar']}`.  I prefer just `$foo[bar]` (for interpolation only -- outside of a string `bar` will be treated as a constant in that context).

Comment: I've seen that in many Coding Styles for consistency the form `${var}` is deprecated and never permitted.

Check the Zend Coding Style [#Variable Substitution](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html)

Comment: @Fabio sounds good to me; I would avoid `${}` altogether.  I would also avoid `{}` except for the couple cases when it's necessary (multi-dimensional array access, method calls, object operator chaining).

Answer (score 4):

The brackets delimit where the variable name ends; this example should speak for itself.

```
$a = "hi!"

echo "$afoo";  //$afoo is undefined

echo "${a}foo";  //hi!foo

echo "{$a}foo";  //hi!foo
```

Also, this should spit out a warning; you should use

```
${'a'}
```

Otherwise it will attempt to assume `a` is a constant.

Comment: `echo "{$a}foo";` should produce the same as `echo "${a}foo";`, the curly braces will not echo to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use **braces** to get Char in the position `$i` of string `$text`:

`$i=2;`
`$text="safi";`

`echo $text{$i}; // f`