# What is {$variable_name} in PHP 5?

Tags: php

What is {$variable_name} in PHP 5?

I think that prints value of $error variable with HTML tag in echo statement.
Am I right?

```
$error = 'this is an error.';
...   
<?php
if (isset($error)) {
    echo "<p> {$error} </p>\n";
}
?>
```

---

But I don't know the difference between `<p> {$error} </p>` and `<p> $error </p>`.

Comment: yes, you are correct

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php

Comment: ... or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422661/php-parser-braces-around-variables

Comment: @Mattia I couldn't find same questions.

Comment: @sebastianbrosch I couldn't find.

Comment: *the answer: YES* - if you are using the search of stackoverflow you can find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422661/php-parser-braces-around-variables with the explanation and examples (and your answer)!

Comment: @ogres 

But I don't know the difference between <p> {$error} </p> and <p> $error </p>.

Comment: @sebastianbrosch I don't know English words well. I'm not American. but thank you.

Comment: there is no difference: `<p> $error </p> === <p> {$error} </p>` please read the informations on the links!

Comment: No difference, but if your variable is a array, use {$variable['item']} to print the value.